# Thermal Energy Transferred into a Larger Object

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm trying to figure something out, and I feel like I'm missing a piece or two of the equation.

If a small solid object (like say a bullet) is embedded into a large solid object (like an armor plate), how much thermal energy is transferred from the bullet into the plate? If my known values are the mass, surface area, specific heat capacity, and average temperature of both objects, is there a way to calculate how much energy will be transferred from the small, hot one into the large, cool one?

Thanks!

Comment: I never really took any thermodynamics courses in school, so I'm guessing at most of this. I use the q=mCΔT formula, and adding the momentum of the bullet at the point of impact (using 1/2*m*v^2)?

Comment: Perfect, that's all I needed to know. Thanks so much!